# unable to get windows 8 comptuer to boot into live CD ubuntu 12.10

Tags: live-cd

I have an Asus X401A, brand new with Windows 8 on it. It malfunctions every single day that I want to smash it to pieces. And so I want to install Ubuntu. I burned a live CD Ubuntu 12.10, but when I restart the computer with the live CD inside the dvd drive, nothing happens, asus just boots into Windows. Why?

Comment: Seems to be UEFI. If you still have problems look at this: http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/17789

Answer (score 0):

You're going to get a ton of the same answers for that question. My guess, as is everyone elses, is that you have to go into your system's bios and change the boot order so that dvd/optical drives are higher than harddrives.

Windows 8 replaces bios with uefi. You wont find a solution in my answer. :( sorry.

Comment: Also, I haven't searched for it, but I bet this question has been asked before and I bet it will be deleted...just sayin...

Comment: Also if your machine uses UEFI (probably if it is new), make sure to select the UEFI dvd device as 1st boot.

Comment: I cannot get into BIOS. I pressed every key on the keypad when rebooting and the computer just boots into Windows. How do you get into BIOS? And I think my computer is uefi.

Comment: omg, this uefi sounds like it should be illegal. I am never upgrading to windows 8, windows xp works just fine in comparison, nothing on the level of ubuntu of course.

Comment: Someone linked some pages on the side here>>>>>>> I think this is what your looking for. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system?lq=1